# docker apache reverse proxy

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose, apache2

Im facing issues getting apache2 to work within docker and to serve as a reverse proxy towards another docker container that is running a Python based API.

My `Dockerfile`

```
FROM httpd:latest
COPY ./httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

httpd.conf:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass        / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8000/
</VirtualHost>

LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so

LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so

LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so

<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
```

When I start the container, I do a curl request to localhost and I face error message:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

If I remove the COPY httpd.conf command from my Dockerfile before building the image, the docker container works without issue as in default out of box I can see the "It works!" page, no proxy of course.

Comment: I think you should have `ServerName` in your config file. Add it and reload Apache to test

Comment: @Saeed just tried with ServerName localhost and no luck

Comment: Where did you add `ServerName localhost` directive? Between `VirtualHost` tag? Also how do you run the container? Are you running it in your own laptop/pc? I asked since you're curling localhost.

Comment: @Saeed I added ServerName localhost under <VirtualHost *:80>. I am running the container on a aws ec2. I installed docker there.

Comment: @Saeed within docker logs for this container I see: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,

Comment: There's no problem with this warning. How do you run container? Could you share the full command?

Comment: @Saeed now I got it to this point:  attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (localhost) failed....docker command: docker run -dit apache2 80:80

Comment: You should run it with `docker run -dp80:80 apache2`. You're using `80:80` at the end which is interpreted that **to run apache2 container with command 80:80**. Try what I wrote and let me kniw

Comment: @Saeed didnt work. I had to add this: ProxyPass / http://172.17.0.1:8000/ and setting that to ip 172.17.0.1 now works. Why is that if you know?

Comment: I think `localhost` in your machine means your machine itself (localhost means your laptop/server/pc, not your container). But curling IP should work as you said.